# Register on new site in-app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I couldn't find how to become a member of a new site inside the app. Tapping my profile just tells me I have none.

For instance I get posts in my feed from sites in which I'm not a member. I wanted to make a comment, but couldn't.

And I know I would receive +100 once I sign up so that's not an issue.

Comment: Also, I was informed that the problem is pretty much specific to making a comment, since that button is hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to vote on any post of new community, after that you will see a join to community dialog, eg:

> [image: join]

When joined you probably need to refresh page if "add comment" button is not visible yet.

Comment: True. Unlike on the web site, the app require you to perform some action in order to actually join a site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard some **non-obvious** action